# How to take pictures in android application without the user Interface..?

Tags: android, camera

I have to design an application, that application has to take the picture from the camera without displaying it in the layout and without any user Interface (like click of a button....) and store the picture?

Answer (score 3):

```
Camera mCamera; 
private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCamera();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

//somewhere in your code call this:
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);


Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap

         FileOutputStream outStream = null;
              try {
                  outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
                  outStream.write(data);
                  outStream.close();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                  Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
              } catch (IOException e){
                  Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
              }

   }
};
```

Comment: call `mCamera.startPreview()` after `safeCameraOpen`, without calling startPreview it won't work