# Take photo in background without UI. Android

Tags: android

i'm looking for code that will take pictures in background and save it to Bitmap. I did some research and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859926/7391954 it kinda works but it freezes UI even if I call takePicture from worker thread and it cannot take photos faster than like 1/sec (I'd like 3/sec). Can anyone help me at this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Take picture without preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754597/android-take-picture-without-preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's camera preview code that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33242595/7391954
 I overlaid my layout on it and then taking photo was as simple as calling `getBitmap()` on that View.

Answer (score 0):

You can use surfaceViewe . 
take a look at this document [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

Comment: I don't want to display preview, it has to take picture in background without UI.

Comment: I know it, you can overlay your main view on surfaceView, or make surfaceView visibility invisible