# Looking for an easy way to capture images on an Android phone as a background service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, android-camera

I'm trying to create an application that automatically clicks pictures as you carry your phone around, the point is that it clicks pictures as you do your own business.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/taking-picture-from-camera-without-preview?noredirect=1&lq=1) is basically what I'm looking for with the added functionality of taking pictures every n seconds. I wanted to know if there was something more efficient than this method (shrinking the preview window to 1x1).

Answer (score 0):

background service is not recommended. You can use foreground service for this job.

You need to give media and camera access permission in the code. Then you can run the capture function with n second delay and while loop as many times as you want.

there are some examples, i don't want to repeat them.
[capture, save and show example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)
[take photo without ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859777/how-to-take-pictures-in-android-application-without-the-user-interface/17859926#17859926)